# Django publish to KAFKA instead of save to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, apache-kafka

We are trying to develop a microservice architecture in Django rest framework where all writes to a SQL database are done by publishing messages to topics on a Apache Kafka messaging system, and all reads are done directly from an SQL database.  This is being done for several reasons, but most importantly it's to have an event log history through Kafka, and to avoid delays due to slower write cycles (reads to databases are usually much faster than writes).

Using signals, it's quite easy to call a Kafka producer method in Django which will publish an event on Kafka showing the model data to be written to db.  However, we don't know how to avoid having the save() method write anything to the database.  We don't want to completely override the save() method as it may cause issues when dealing with ManytoMany relationships.

Does someone have a simple suggestion to avoid database writes but still do database reads in Django? Please keep in mind that we still want to use the conventional method to read from the SQL database using Django models.

Comment: What's stopping you from removing the `save()` method call on your models? You just don't call it. You don't need to override anything.

Comment: I'm not very experienced in Django but as I understand the save() method does more than saving.  It also does field validation etc.  If I don't call the save method on the model, it will skip the field validation completely as an example, won't it? This is why my idea was to somehow find a way to use the save() method but not actually execute a write to the database.

Comment: Django may validate the model, sure, but Kafka has no such thing, so I suggest you extract whatever validation process away from Django

Comment: Similar boat. I'm new to a proj already using DRF + traditional RDMS. Currently advocating to NOT dual-write to DB + message bus (eg, with signals or app code, OR change data capture) and INSTEAD make the event stream the single-source-of-truth. Bookmarking this thread for later

Comment: We were was originally planning a microservice architecture and using the message bus as the single source of truth for communicating between microservices.  Our original plan was to have no database at all connected to the microservice.  However, we soon realized that working in this way is quite complicated when using Django because Django always assumes reads and writes to a database.  So now, we are at the stage where we are using a local db with the microservice and also need to publish and consume events from the event bus.  Hope this clarifies.